# Matrix Algebra Theorem

Tags: matrices

Let the matrix $A \in \mathbb{K}^{m \times n}$ such that : $A.X = \textbf{0} $, $\forall X \in \mathbb{K}^{n \times 1}$. 
Prove that $A = \textbf{0}$

Note that $\textbf{0}$ means the matrix whose all its elements are null.

Comment: Can you find an $X$ such that $AX$ is exactly one of the columns of $A$? Now, what can you say?

Comment: That was my idea, if I give 1 to the first element of $X$ and the others 0 because it would have a column of zeroes of A so I would change the order in which I choose 1 and I would get to that A is 0 but I wanted to formalize a little because of that my Question.

Comment: The columns of a transformation matrix are the images of the basis.

Answer (score 0):

From the equation $Ax = 0,\forall x\in \mathbb K^{n\times 1}$ we conclude that the nullity of $A$ is $\operatorname{null}(A) = \dim\ker A =n$ , where $\ker A = \{ x \in \mathbb K^{n\times 1}: Ax = 0\}= \mathbb K^n.$

According to the [rank-nullity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem), we have:
$$ \operatorname{rank}(A) + \operatorname{null}(A) = n.$$

However, $\operatorname{null}(A) = n\implies \operatorname{rank}A = 0\implies A = 0.$